# Built In functions browsers support in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, browser-support

Is there a list of builtin functions (in default objects prototypes) and browsers that support them? I was wondering about functions like:

- `Array.prototype.map`
- `Array.prototype.forEach`
- `Function.prototype.bind`

But there are probably more builtin functions like that, Are they listed somewhere with they browser support? I search but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a list in [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/).

Answer (score 0):

[DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/) is very helpful in that regard, or the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

Comment: It's more of documentation but it point to `Kangax's compat tables`.